# Trying out the audio clip

Tags: java, audio, javasound, malformedurlexception

Whenever I try the audio clip, I get this error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /Users/videogames/Documents/workspace/TryApplets/res/adv.wav---------
```

What's the problem? Here's the code for the program. (I use a mac, if that matters at all)

```
package game;

import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;

public class sound {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        URL url = new URL("/Users/videogames/Documents/workspace/TryApplets/res/adv.wav");
        AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        clip.play();
        } catch (MalformedURLException murle) {
        System.out.println(murle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, don't use an [`AudioClip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AudioClip.html), Java Sound provides the much more enabled [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html).

Answer (score 2):

An URL must start with something like `http://..` or `file://..`.  The URL shown does not, it is not a valid URL.

Answer (score 2):

Valid protocols for the URL class are

```
 http, https, ftp, file, and jar
```

so try

```
URL url = new URL("file://Users/videogames/Documents/workspace/TryApplets/res/adv.wav");
```

If in doubt read the API

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String)

Comment: what is this comment supposed to mean?

Comment: when I started it, it immediatly terminated without playing the clip.

Comment: The Java Sound based `Clip` as well as (I suspect) the applet based `AudioClip` run on daemon `Thread` instances.  See the [Java Sound info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for source that gets around that (by showing a GUI).